# NextJS images are not shown using "export" script

Tags: next.js, next-images

I have a simple NextJs app.

When I'm running the app on a localhost everything seems to work fine - All the images are shown as expected

When I use this script: next build && next export
and browse to my local build, I don't see the images, but instead its "alt" text

The way I import an image:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

import someImage from '../../../public/images/some-image.png';


const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Image
                src={someImage}
                alt="Some Image"
                placeholder="blur"
            />
        </div>
}
```

next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const configuration = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
        dirs: ['./src'],
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    images: {
        loader: 'akamai',
        path: '',
    },
};

module.exports = configuration;
```

My code design:
[image: My code design]

**Environment:**
"next": "13.1.6",
"react": "18.2.0",

Moreover, I tried to use a normal img tag and it causes the same problem.

If anyone here faces the same issue ill appreciate any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to this page:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api

```
You are attempting to run next export while importing the next/image component using the default loader configuration.

However, the default loader relies on the Image Optimization API which is not available for exported applications.
```

So, when running static NextJS app with `export` you cannot use NextJS optimization, as it should run in your non-existent server. You should use cloud solution (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration) or remove optimization:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
}
```

(https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized)

Answer (score 0):

When importing something statically from the public folder it already knows youre inside it. You only need the following import:

```
import someImage from 'images/some-image.png';
```

Comment: Still causes the same problem

Comment: Try saving your image somewhere except your public folder

Comment: I cannot accept such a solution which is incompatible with nextjs docs

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didnt catch that you wanted static served. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use next js optimized Image tag when exporting static files/runing npm run export. You can refer to next js official documentation to check that which tags don't work with export out command. As an alternative replace all Image tags in your application with img tag and remove import Next/Images lines from all files and also add unoptimised image option in next js config file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).